# jhipster entity - what exactly is that?

Tags: entity, yeoman, jhipster

I am wondering what jhipster entities are exactly?
What if I just want to create a new page/view without any database entry and relationship? For example: the about page, do I have to use the entity generator in order to create it? What are the benefits of it?

[jhipster entity tutorial](http://jhipster.github.io/creating_an_entity.html)

Regards

redyar

Answer (score 1):

Entities are typically objects that are backed by a database table. With JHipster, you can generate entities (and their associated screens) using Yeoman.

For an about page, or any other page, you can author them by hand. You don't need to use a generator. JHipster merely provides its entity sub-generator as a convenience for you.

You can also use the Yeoman generator for AngularJS to generate basic scaffolding.

http://yeoman.io

Answer (score -1):

Immagine to build a website of e-commerce. That website contains users, sensible data informations, details about sellers and other things. You can save a lot of time creating it with Jhipster because it automatically create Objects class that represents database's tables, RESTful web services to manage them and the frontend view with Angular, CSS and HTML (all generated automatically). The objects that represent database's tables are **entities**.

With entities you can do CRUD queries on database using Java objects and Java methods with Spring framework. You can do queries by calling java methods. Thats all! After some practice it's really easy to use.

With that generator you don't have to configure relationships, constraints or things like that. Jhipster does that for you!

If you need a web application that does not use a database you don't need to use a generator like this, in my opinion.

I took the right Matt Raible's answer trying to give you more informations about entities. I hope to be helpful!

Have a nice day!